# MySQL: Execute commands

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to drop all tables from a database, but before I drop them I need to do the following:

```
$MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0"
```

The above commands does not seem to work. How can I set the FK to 0 before I drop in a bash scrip?

I found out what I did wrong:

```
$MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0"
$MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST -e "drop table $t"
```

These are two different sessions, so I did:

```
$MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; drop table $t;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`. By default, the setting only affects the session where it's run -- which exits immediately.

Comment: Thanks you helped me figure it out.